# Specifying the # of hidden units in Facebook fasttext

Tags: facebook, nlp, text-classification, fasttext

In the [paper on fasttext](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01759v3.pdf) for supervised classification, the authors specified various quantities of hidden units by altering some parameter  (h is the one on pages 3,4 - In table 1 you see "It has 10 hidden units and we evaluate it with and without bigrams.") But after reading [the documentation](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/README.md#full-documentation) it does not appear that there is a "hidden unit" parameter to alter.  Is there a way to specify the number of hidden units? Or is this the same as specifying the -dim option?

Comment: From the facebook group page: I would like to ask, when using Fasttext for classification, what is the number of nodes used in the neural net softmax ?  --Number of nodes in softmax layer is same as number of your classes (or little more for hierarchical softmax). Then there is a hidden layer which size is set by you (wit -dim).--  This is consistent with the answer below so accepting.

Answer (score 0):

**`k` is the no. of classes**

From Section 2.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01759v3.pdf

> More precisely, the computational complexity is O(kh) where k is the number of classes and h the dimension of the text representation.

---

**When predicting classes in text classification**, from the [docs](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText#text-classification):

> The argument k is optional, and is equal to 1 by default.
>   In order to obtain the k most likely labels for a piece of text, use:
>
> $ ./fasttext predict model.bin test.txt k

---

**When training the model**, this is implicitly specified in the training data when performing supervised training with the `__label__*` tag.

From the [example tutorial](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/tutorials/supervised-learning.md#getting-and-preparing-the-data):

```
$ wget https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fasttext-vectors/cooking.stackexchange.tar.gz && tar xvzf cooking.stackexchange.tar.gz
--2017-05-23 09:03:26--  https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fasttext-vectors/cooking.stackexchange.tar.gz
Resolving s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com... 54.231.236.45
Connecting to s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com|54.231.236.45|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 457609 (447K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘cooking.stackexchange.tar.gz.1’

cooking.stackexchange.tar.gz.1      100%[================================================================>] 446.88K   385KB/s    in 1.2s    

2017-05-23 09:03:28 (385 KB/s) - ‘cooking.stackexchange.tar.gz.1’ saved [457609/457609]

x cooking.stackexchange.id
x cooking.stackexchange.txt
x readme.txt


$ cat readme.txt 
The data in this archive is derived from the user-contributed content on the
Cooking Stack Exchange website (https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), used under
CC-BY-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

The original data dump can be downloaded from:
https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/cooking.stackexchange.com.7z
and details about the dump obtained from:
https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

We distribute two files, under CC-BY-SA 3.0:

 - cooking.stackexchange.txt, which contains all question titles and
   their associated tags (one question per line, tags are prefixed by
   the string "__label__") ;

 - cooking.stackexchange.id, which contains the corresponding row IDs,
   from the original data dump.
```